# Span float left not working in Safari?

Tags: html, css, safari, css-float

I created this countdown ([code here](http://jsfiddle.net/yentup/cQXx3/)), and for some reason the numbers seem to be going downwards in Safari, instead of left to right.

The spans are not too wide or anything, (`width: 150px;`) so i dont know why this is happening.

Does anyone know what is causing this or how to fix it?

I've tested it in Chrome and Firefox, and it works fine, but i dont know about IE.

Comment: Works for me in Chrome/Win7, Firefox/Win7

Comment: Just tested it. Looks the same in Safari as in Chrome.

Comment: How are you testing your code (besides in JSFiddle)? Running from a localhost?

Comment: Yes, but it's on my site [here](http://donutdev.com/countdown/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove `display: table;` from `.nums` and `display: table-cell;` from `.nums span`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cQXx3/1/)

CSS

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Quicksand Book';
    src: url('http://donutdev.com/fonts/Quicksand_Book.otf');
}

#headr {
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    font-size: 50px;
}

#countdown {
    width: 600px;
    height: 166px;
    background-color: #212121;
    border-radius: 7px;
    display: none;
}

.nums {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    height: 90px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Quicksand Book', sans-serif;
    font-size: 50px;
}

.nums span {
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #dcdcdc;
}

.text {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Verdana', sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #dcdcdc;
}
```

Comment: Hmm.. This does work, but then the numbers arent vertically centered. Is there another way to vertically center the numbers?

Comment: @yentup what you do is make `span` as an inline block level element and give `padding-top` http://jsfiddle.net/cQXx3/2/ not keep both demos side by side and take a look